# How to fix this custom transformer in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I've written this simple custom transformer that fills na in specific columns with 0. When I fit_transform on my dataset, it does not fill nas in the specified columns. I've failed to see the problem in my code.

```
class CustomImputer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin): 
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        for col in ('PavedDrive', 'GarageQual', 'GarageFinish', 'FireplaceQu', 'KitchenQual', 'CentralAir', 'HeatingQC', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtCond', 'BsmtQual', 'ExterCond', 'ExterQual', 'Street'):
            X[col].fillna(0)
        return X
```

I expected the returned dataframe to be one where the specified columns have filled nas with 0 however, I get a dataframe with the same null values.

Comment: Now you see how crucial it is to indent your code properly. It simply leads to confusion

Comment: You're right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never assigned the `fillna` operation to a new variable.  Using

```
X[col].fillna(0)
```

does not happen in-place.  Instead use:

```
X.loc[:,col] = X[col].fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner solution would be

```
cols = ['PavedDrive', 'GarageQual', 'GarageFinish', 'FireplaceQu', 'KitchenQual', 'CentralAir', 'HeatingQC', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtCond', 'BsmtQual', 'ExterCond', 'ExterQual', 'Street']

X.loc[:,cols] = X[cols].fillna(0)
```